# GAPlugin is not pushing Data to Google analytics

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics

I am using the [Official](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin/) phonegap plugin for GoogleAnalytic to track my App.

The plugin has been installed and worked Correctly but I didn't find any data on google analytic page.

My code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gaPlugin;

            function initialize() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            }

            function onDeviceReady() {
                gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
                gaPlugin.init(nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "UA-34640387-3", 10);
              }

            function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
                alert('nativePluginResultHandler - '+result);
                console.log('nativePluginResultHandler: '+result);

            }

            function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) {
                alert('nativePluginErrorHandler - '+error);
                console.log('nativePluginErrorHandler: '+error);
            }

            function TrackButtonClicked() {
                gaPlugin.trackEvent( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "Button", "Click", "event only", 1);
            }

            function VariableButtonClicked() {
                gaPlugin.setVariable( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, 1, "Purple");
                gaPlugin.trackEvent( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "event with variable", "set variable", "favoriteColor", 1);
            }

            function PageButtonClicked() {
                gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "some.url.com");
            }

            function goingAway() {
                gaPlugin.exit(nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler);
            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long did you wait?

It takes between 24 and 48 hours for data to appear under the standard reports in the Google Analytics website.   You could try and check the Real-time reports some of your data may appear there.

Comment: Thanks, I made some calls to other developers that they used this plugin before, and they answers the same.